# Devo aceitar edições com tradução da pergunta?

Tags: suporte

Consegui há pouco tempo reputação para poder analisar as edições sugeridas. Gostaria de saber o que fazer com as sugestões que traduzem uma pergunta feita em inglês. Quando eu vejo uma pergunta em inglês, eu só sinalizo com fora do escopo.

No caso, essa [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157360/51124) estava em inglês e outro usuário sugeriu a [edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/83011) com a tradução.

Minha dúvida: Devo aceitar sugestão de edição com a tradução da pergunta feita originalmente em outro idioma?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normalmente deve aceitar sim, é útil para o site e resolve um problema, que é o que buscamos. Claro que a tradução tem que refletir o que estava no original.

Esse caso me parece bem útil. Quem traduziu poderia ter tirado o texto inútil. Quem vai aceitar pode melhorar o que não foi editado.

E seria bom que a pergunta não tivesse outros problemas, afinal pra que traduzir algo que será fechado de qualquer jeito? Mas isso não é obrigatório.

Comment: Obrigada @bigown =)